# Shift + / Key combination not getting detected by javascript in Firefox on Mac OSX

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, macos

This javascript code always returns zero for " Shift + / " key combination on Firefox 3.6.3 on OSX 10.5.8
But it returns the expected value 191 on Chrome on OSX/mac

```
GetKeyCode = function(e) {
        var code = 0;
        if (!e) {
            e = window.event
        }
        if (e.keyCode) { 
            code = e.keyCode;
        } else if (e.which) { 
            code = e.which;
        }
        return code;
    };
```

GetKeyCode is getting **keydown**  event from jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function(e) { ...... });
```

Is there any bug, or am I missing something very simple here?
Please help

Thanks in advance.
-Parimal Das

Comment: How is `GetKeyCode` attached? To which event, on which element? Have a look at http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html for more information about keyboard events.

Comment: Its a keydown event. I have updated the post too.
Thanks.

Comment: Why did you make this Community Wiki?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you don't need to normalize the Event interface. But it works in my Firefox (3.6.3/Linux) and Chromium (5.0.375.70) when using: `jQuery(document).keydown(function(e) { var code = 0; if (e.keyCode) { code = e.keyCode; } else if (e.which) { code = e.which; } console.log(code); });`. Perhaps something Mac-specific?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Firefox which is specific to Mac OSX:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=448434

This happens for a few other keys: period, comma and dash when shift is held.

The following page documents this and many other browser variations on key events:

http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Answer (score 0):

If it's coming from jQuery, you should be able to use `e.which` only. In fact, looking for `e.keyCode` may be causing the problem, since it's not populated if the Shift key is down. See [the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.charCode#Notes).

Comment: I think you confuse `keyCode` with `charCode`: "`charCode` is never set in the keydown  and keyup  events. In these cases, `keyCode` is set instead." Also look at [event.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.keyCode): "`keyCode` is always set in the keydown  and keyup  events. In these cases, `charCode` is never set."

Comment: But you're right about jQuery normalizing `event.which`: "While browsers use differing properties to store this information, jQuery normalizes the `.which` property so we can reliably use it to retrieve the key code. This code corresponds to a key on the keyboard, including codes for special keys such as arrows. For catching actual text entry, `.keypress()` may be a better choice.

Comment: Actually I'd avoid keydown/keyup except in some edge cases e.g. modifier keys. Stick to keypress if you can.